# How to detect if a computer has the new Chromium-based Edge browser installed?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I am building a WPF application to run specifically on Windows 10 computers which will contain a web browser control. The preferred browser is the new Chromium-based Edge browser. Although I know I can be sure Edge will be installed, I can't be sure it will be the new Chromium-based version. I need to implement a fall-back (perhaps the Internet Explorer browser control), but in order to decide whether or not to fall back, I need to know if the preferred browser is available.

I know that all Windows 10 computers RS4 (1803) and above will eventually receive it as a regular update, but I need to support the fallback case for such computers which have not yet received the update. I also know that LTSC computers (pre-RS4) will *never* receive the update and need to support the fallback case for these computers too.

I have considered CefSharp, but the ~100MB redistributable size makes it unsuitable; I need to keep the size of the application package to a minimum because of bandwith constraints in package delivery, so need to leverage what is already on the computer.

So, my question is: how can a WPF application detect if the Chromium-based Edge browser is present on the computer?

Comment: Do you really need to use the default web browser control? If not, you could try using a Chromium browser like CefSharp. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp

Comment: @AMA CefSharp would work except that it is a ~100MB package. Due to considerations concerning application package distribution, I need to keep the installable size to a minimum, so need to use a browser that already exists on the machine.

Comment: Would it suffice to check if fileversion of msedge.exe is >=79.0.309 ?

Comment: @AMA Perhaps, but I found that one computer having the Edge Canary preview has msedge.exe in two places: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Edge SXS\Application and %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Edge SXS\Application\81.0.394.0, where another Windows 10 computer which has only the legacy Edge browser has no msedge.exe anywhere.

Comment: I am unsure why the application would exist under the user's local app data. Does a path exist to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe ? As for Edge legacy, the executable is in fact not called msedge.exe, but MicrosoftEdge.exe and exists under C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe

Comment: @AMA From a little further research I found that my folder anomaly is not unique; likely related to the fact that I installed a Canary build and/or how I installed it.

Comment: did you find a resolution for this issue?